# The longer Nemo is open the slower it becomes to gain focus

Tags: linux-mint, application, nemo

I am using Nemo v 3.8.6 with Mint 19 and if I have Nemo open and leave this application running within an hour it is completely unusable, taking maybe 50 seconds to switch focus to it, this doesn't lock any other processes, but I have to keep focus if I want to use anything in Nemo.

Once I am inside Nemo it runs a lot faster, but still with very very clear lag.

Interestingly if I am moving images around folders, it will have the same effect as above and lot lot faster.

Closing all windows and opening again restarts everything back to normal.